# Unix grep a string then only show the string in the list

Tags: unix, sorting, grep

Can anyone help to show me how to do this.

I use netstat to find out how many servers are currently connected to my servers, and I've got the following list, server001 and 002 has a number of services connected to myserver01

```
myserver01.1050    server001.com.51535 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server001.com.36565 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server002.com.35262 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server002.com.41700 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server002.com.36525 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server002.com.54575 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server001.com.44401 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server001.com.47922 64860      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
myserver01.1050    server001.com.57080 49680      0 49680      0 ESTABLISHED
```

Can anyone tell me how can I grep or sort the list , which I could get a unique server name, something like the one below

```
myserver01.1050    server001.com
myserver01.1050    server002.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat netstat.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f2 | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u
```

Comment: I think that yields a single name, not pairs of names as required.

Comment: Yes I took some liberties and wrote it to only show single unique server names, stripped of what looked like redundant information.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cut -d'.' -f1-3 input | sort | uniq
myserver01.1050    server001.com
myserver01.1050    server002.com
```

and using `uniq -c` you can get a count as well

```
$ cut -d'.' -f1-3 input | sort | uniq -c
      5 myserver01.1050    server001.com
      4 myserver01.1050    server002.com
```

Comment: First version, in fewer chars: `cut -d'.' -f1-3 input | sort -u`

Answer (score 2):

This is a little ugly, but it works (`6333197.txt` containing your netstat output):

```
$ cat 6333197.txt | awk -F '.' '{print $1"."$2"."$3}' | sort -u
```

`-F` defines the input field separator, ([awk man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/awk.html))

Comment: That's not ugly, that beautiful shell minimalism ;-)... Oh wait, no need for the extra process for uniq, use `sort -u` ;-)!

Comment: @shellter, the shorter the better ;-) thanks - slashed `uniq`.

Comment: [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) award contender, but otherwise very neat.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

It can all be done in 1 line awk command like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/\.[0-9]*$/, "", $2); serv[$2]=$1;} END{n=asorti(serv, dest); for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print serv[dest[i]] " " dest[i];}' file.txt
```

#### OUTPUT (with above input):

```
myserver01.1050 server001.com
myserver01.1050 server002.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $ grep myserver01.1050 logfile | \
    grep ' server' | \
    awk -F\. '{print $1, $2}' | \
    sort -u
```

Although I can't tell whether you want only the server name or only the pair of names. Kind of guessing, so sorry if I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: thanks mate, yes, I only want the server name, and only want to have the unique ones.

Answer (score 0):

That's a version using `sed` and `sort -u`:

```
sed 's/^\(\S\S*\s\s*\S\S*\)\.[0-9][0-9]*\s.*/\1/' filename | sort -u
```

resp. with GNU version of `sed` ans `sort -u`:

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+\s+\S+)\.[0-9]+\s.*/\1/' filename | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and `sort`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'  filename | sort -u
```